# Converting an ASP.NET website to a native Android/iOS app

Tags: android, asp.net, ios, cross-platform

I have an ASP.NET website I want to convert to a downloadable native app for iOS/Android devices.
I was wondering if this was at all possible - I am aware of all the tweaks required to make the website mobile-friendly (server/client wise), but I'm currently unaware of how to compile the website as a native app.

Also, since my site has server-side logic, the native app should work like my normal website, sending and receiving data between the client and server.

Thanks,
Ron

Comment: What do you mean by *compile the website as a native app*?

Answer (score 1):

While you are right that a native app and a website are similar that they send and receive data from the server, that's probably the only similarity.

As a concept native apps and websites are very different and I don't think you can expect to convert between the two. Depending on how the website is implemented, it might be more work or less work.

ASP.NET encourages a development model where you don't think about the client and server as separate entities and tries to abstract the technology underneath (HTTP, HTML, web server). This is why most ASP.NET websites are usually implemented in a way which you wouldn't follow when developing an app.

I think your best bet is to either make the existing site mobile-friendly or just implement a native app from scratch. For info about the first suggestion, you can read Scott Hanselman's [blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CreateAGreatMobileExperienceForYourWebsiteTodayPlease.aspx). As for native apps, I'm sure you can find many resources through Google.

Comment: Is it possible to make the web site mobile-friendly and then only create a native app that only has an invisible browser that directs only to the website?

Comment: Yes. On iPhone you can directly put a shortcut to the web site on your home screen and it will look like an app. On android, I think you have to make an application that contains a WebView and point to your website: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Answer (score 1):

For the fast solution, create a mobile friendly responsive CSS for your existing site and use Cordova/Apache Phonegap shell to embed it as initial page.

If your ASP.NET page is developed using MVC, I would suggest you to write another HTML5 page that uses ASP.NET Web API and use it with Cordova. Of course, you can also choose to develop a native app in a native language of the platform (like Swift in IOS or J2ME in Android) if you can convert it to WEB API structure.

It would be very hard to convert old-styled ASP.NET apps to mobile native apps. Once, I wrote a Cordava hybrid app for a similar issue that uses a browser object to open some local and server pages on the native app. Native part was used for header and tab control navigation. Hybrid apps are like native apps, you can download from app store / google play but they uses internal web browsers to show the content. Some part of your app can be still native.

If you are interested in this Web/Hybrid app development approach, you can also look at [Ionic Framework](http://ionicframework.com/).

Look at [Hybrid](http://www.icenium.com/blog/icenium-team-blog/2012/06/14/what-is-a-hybrid-mobile-app-) apps and [Cordova](http://cordova.apache.org/) for the start. Good luck!